# Why does my eclipse IDE run without compiler error when I create a non static inner class with static methods and variables?

Tags: java, eclipse

Member inner classes can’t have static members in them. When my friend ran the same code on her eclipse IDE she got a compiler error for a static member in a non static inner class. When I run the code there are no errors. Why?

This is the code:

```
public class Outer {
    class Inner {
        static void method() {
            System.out.println("Static method in Inner Class");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than *describing* the code, please *show* the code - also give details about the versions of Java you and your friend are using.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your compiler compliance level set to Java 16 (or above). The language specification was changed to allow static members and methods in inner classes in Java 16 - see [JLS §8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). This was included as part of the [JEP 395](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395)

With the compliance level set to Java 15 or before Eclipse will reject static methods or members in a inner class.